# A thread in multi-threaded program much slower than a thread in sequential program (single-threaded)

Tags: java, multithreading

My program processes 6 million rows of data; it does a filter operation for a DB.
It is written in Java with TornadoVM.
There is a sequential (single-threaded) version and a multi-threaded version of the program.
In the multi-threaded version of the program, each thread processes pre-processed partitioned data.
If your CPU has 8 cores, each thread in the multi-threaded version processes each of 1/8 portion of the original data.

The current problem is that the speed of each thread in the multi-threaded version of the program is much slower than a thread in the single-threaded version of the program (4x slower).

For example, let's say we run the same file with 6 millions of lines of data. In the single-threaded sequential version, it runs like 100ms.
In the multi-threaded version however, if we input 1 file of the same data (without partitioning), it takes like 400ms although they process the exact same file and it is also the same that each program has only one thread running.

Can anyone help with this problem?

So I made sure that the time taken for the multi-threaded version excludes the overhead of thread initialization. The time taken only includes the time taken for filter operations for each version of the program.

Comment: Wherever the input is coming from, ultimately it isn’t multi-threaded.

Comment: If you're literally reading from a database, IO bound processes cannot be sped up with threads.  The extra time for the multi-threaded code is likely overhead of thread start-up, followed by no improvement.

Comment: Not possible to answer without a lot more details. The contention for file or database access may be the cause, or perhaps you aren't using batch updates in JDBC.

Answer (score 2):

100ms is already quite fast. Unless you show us the code, we can only make assumptions. Does most of the overhead come from IO i.e. reading from the file? Is there any waiting time involved of any kind i.e. job/task assigning to a thread? Do all threads work asynchronously at the same time (other threads start only start when the one before them finishes)? is there any locking involved when reading from the file?

When benchmarking this sort of thing, one thing that helps in getting accurate results is running the code multiple times in the same run. JVM warm up, caching etc reduces variance.

Answer (score 2):

There is insufficient information to determine what is actually going on.  But if your single-threaded version processed 6 million rows in 100ms, the work *per row* must be tiny.  In the order of 10ns.  That's nanoseconds.  And that includes file I/O and / or database overheads.

It is conceivable that the reason the multi-threaded version is slower is that the overheads of reading rows and dispatching them to threads is significantly larger than the ~10ns per row of processing.  Another theory is that your processing involves accessing / updating a shared data structure, and your concurrency design is suboptimal.

What to do?

1. The simple answer is to not do anything.  100ms to process 6 million (input) rows is FAST.
2. Split the input file into 8 (or however many) and then either run a 8 copies of the program, or 8 threads that each process a separate file.  But this depends on what the processing is actually doing and what the actually concurrency bottleneck is.  We can only speculate ...